# Is it possible to add a hourglass to the cursor?

Tags: vbscript

I want a vbscript.vbs that will add a hourglass to the cursor or completely changes the cursor into hourglass and cursor changes to standard mode at the end of script.

I searched Google a lot but didn't find anything.I haven't even tried a single line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As he said ***"destination-data"***  ==> VBS doesn't include this functionality.

But if you wrap your VBScript inside a HTA, you can found a workaround for this

**[Here is an example in HTA found here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1387465)**

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <STYLE>
      .clsAccKey:first-letter {text-decoration: underline}
      BUTTON {width: 15ex}
    </STYLE>
    <SCRIPT language=VBScript>
      Option Explicit

      Sub btnClick_onclick()
        btnClick.disabled = True
        document.body.style.cursor = "wait"
        btnClick.style.cursor = "wait"
        'Long delay here just to simulate a long
        'running process visually for this demo.
        setTimeout "HiThere", 2000, "VBScript"
      End Sub

      Sub HiThere()
        document.body.style.cursor = "default"
        btnClick.style.cursor = "default"
        MsgBox "Hi There!"
        btnClick.disabled = False
      End Sub
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <BUTTON id=btnClick accessKey=C class=clsAccKey>Click Me</BUTTON>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And i used it in this example : **Execution a powershell file with HTA**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Execution a powershell file with HTA by Hackoo</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Execution a powershell file with HTA by Hackoo"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
     ICON="Winver.exe"
     SCROLL="no"
/>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Sub Run_PS_Script()
    ExampleOutput.value = ""
    btnClick.disabled = True
    document.body.style.cursor = "wait"
    btnClick.style.cursor = "wait"
    Dim WshShell,Command,PSFile,return,fso,file,text,Temp
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Temp = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    Command = "cmd /c echo Get-WmiObject Win32_Process ^| select ProcessID,ProcessName,Handle,commandline,ExecutablePath ^| Out-File %temp%\output.txt -Encoding ascii > %temp%\process.ps1"
    PSFile = WshShell.Run(Command,0,True)
    return = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File %temp%\process.ps1", 0, true)
    Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(Temp &"\output.txt", 1)
    text = file.ReadAll 
    ExampleOutput.Value=text
    file.Close
    document.body.style.cursor = "default"
    btnClick.style.cursor = "default"
    btnClick.disabled = False   
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="123456">
<textarea id="ExampleOutput" style="width:100%" rows="37"></textarea>
<br>
<center><input type="button" name="btnClick" value="Run powershell script file " onclick="Run_PS_Script()"></center> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

VBS doesn't include this functionality.

By default .vbs files are executed by the Windows Script Host, which doesn't provide a method for updating the cursor either.  If you are using another host this may provide a method.

Assuming you are looking for a way to track the progress of your script there are some workarounds.

**Method 1**

Executing your script via the command line provides a UI, which you output progress to.

**Method 2**

Wrap your VBScript inside a [HTA](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx).  This will provide a one page HTML UI.  You could include some sort of progress indicator here.